# How to Web Deploy to a server with Windows 8.1 and VS 2013?

Tags: wcf, visual-studio, iis, web, windows-8

I'm trying to deploy a WCF-Service on my server with VS 2013 Professional.
Server:
- IIS 8.5
- Windows 8.1
- Web Deploy 3.5

I followed the steps on [Deploy a Web Project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465337.aspx).
But I can't make it work..
Now I get an error:

> Fehler beim Lesen der IIS-Konfigurationsdatei 'MACHINE/REDIRECTION'. Die Identität, die diesen Vorgang ausgeführt hat, lautet 'Server\User'.
>   Dateiname: \?\C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\config\redirection.config
>   Fehler: Die Konfigurationsdatei kann aufgrund unzureichender Berechtigungen nicht gelesen werden.

It means that the User has no rights to read the file.
I did allow all users to acces the file and config folder with no effect.
Additionaly

[image]

The WMSVC and MsDepSvc-Services are active.

Did someone else try to Web Deploy with VS 2013 and Windows 8-Server?
Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

This [article](http://www.iis.net/learn/install/installing-publishing-technologies/installing-and-configuring-web-deploy-on-iis-80-or-later) at IIs.net says that running the Web Management Service can not be done on 8 or 8.1.

> Windows 8.0 and 8.1 do not come with the Web Management Service that is required for remote connections. For more information, see Remote Publishing Cannot Be Set up on Windows 8.0 or 8.1.

Have found nothing to contradict so far.

Comment: The full text is  as follows in case people think they are installing the missing components, it STILL WILL NOT WORK: "You cannot set up remote publishing using Web Deploy for a site that is hosted in IIS on Windows 8.0 or 8.1. The reason is that the client SKUs for Windows do not come with the Web Management Service that is required for remote connections. As a result, on Windows 8.0 or 8.1, the IIS Manager Permissions icon and the Configure Web Deploy Publishing deployment option that are required to configure remote publishing are not available in the IIS Manager."

Comment: Is it true even if I want to run Web Deploy only on localhost through msdeploy.axd? I'm a developer and I want to experiment with Publish Profiles on my local machine before I go to a server.

Answer (score 1):

You've specified `http://server/msdeployagentservice` for your server, which is incorrect. All you need to do is specify the server/DNS name and Web Deploy work everything else out.

If you are still having problems, in your browser visit `https://serverName:8172/msdeploy.axd` - if everything is working ok you should be asked for a username/password, you'll also be alerted that there's an SSL certificate issue. If you can't connect at all then you might want to verify port 8172 is open on the server.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you. If I try to use https with port 8172, no connection is possible. I verified that the port is opened and even deactivated the firewall.  
  
There is an option to enable remote connections in the IIS Management Service. But I can't install the Management Service under IIS 8.5 and Windows 8.1: See 
[link](http://www.orcsweb.com/blog/peter/configure-iis-8-remote-administration/)  
  
`http://server/msdeployagentservice` is equivalent to `http://server` and should work for privat networks without SSL certification. So I don't understand why I get that error.

Comment: Try configuring the management service identity credentials to `Windows credentials only`. You can find this configuration in the IIS Manager server level > Management > Management Service.

Comment: The problem is, that I can't install the Management Service on Windows 8.1. So I don't have the option in the IIS Manager.

Comment: I'm using IIS 8.0 Express on Windows 8.1.